# Delete data from Database inside RecycleView

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

I need your help. I want to delete data from my Database by SwipeToDelete inside the RecyclerView.

I've already a Swipe class that deletes items from the RecycleView and I'm able to remove items from that list but not from the database.

I 've tried to call database inside the NoteAdapater (Recycler Adapter) and delete the item that I want with the method removeItem(int position) like this:

```
public void removeItem(int position){
    db.deleteNote(position);
    noteList.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

Here's the MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView recyclerView;
NoteAdapter adapter;
List<Note> myList;
FloatingActionButton fab;
DBHelper db = new DBHelper(this);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    initializeViews();

    myList = db.getAllNotes();
    adapter = new NoteAdapter(this,myList);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addNewNote();
        }
    });

    ItemTouchHelper.Callback callback = new Swipe(adapter);
    ItemTouchHelper helper = new ItemTouchHelper(callback);
    helper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

}
```

Code from database that deletes data:

```
public void deleteNote(int note){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_ID + " = ?",new String[] {String.valueOf(note)});
}
```

Comment: do you get any error while removing or what?

Comment: @AlexanderPerfilyev I get a NullPointeException. I think that Im not initialize my DatabaseHelper correct...

Comment: yep, just pass `db` as a constructor parameter to your adapter and it should work.

Comment: @AlexanderPerfilyev I'll give it a try. Thanks for help

Comment: @AlexanderPerfilyev Now, I can delete the row, but a new one is being auto-added. The same row that I delete, is the same that added... Any extra help?

Comment: are you sure it was deleted from the database? install [stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/) and check your database

Comment: @AlexanderPerfilyev The item is still inside my database...:/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is here `db.deleteNote(position);` Your query says that you are deleting an item with id equal to passed parameter `deleteNote(int note)`.

So what you need to do is to pass a note id, not a position. Something like:

```
db.deleteNote(noteList.get(position).getId());
```

Comment: Yes, that was it. Finally my code works. Thanks Alexander. Appreciate your help.

Comment: hey can you please help over here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63266686/how-do-i-remove-row-from-recyclerview-using-room/63297383?noredirect=1#comment112047918_63297383