# How do I remove a row from recyclerview using room?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room, android-livedata, delete-row

I'm trying to delete an row of recyclerview using room.im doing swipe to delete a particular row....

Here is my Address table-->

```
@Entity(tableName = "address")
 class Address {
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
var id = 0

@ColumnInfo(name = "address")
var address: String? = null
 }
```

AddressDao:

```
@Dao
interface AddressDao {
@Insert
suspend fun addData(address: Address)

@Query("select * from address")
fun getAddressesWithChanges() :LiveData<MutableList<Address>>

@Query("SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM address WHERE id=:id)")
suspend fun isAddressAdded(id: Int): Int

@Delete
suspend fun delete(address: Address)
  }
```

Database:

```
@Database(entities = [Address::class], version = 1)
abstract class Database : RoomDatabase() {
abstract fun AddressDao(): AddressDao
 }
```

AddressActivity:

```
class AddressActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val adapter = AddressAdapter()

    private lateinit var data: LiveData<MutableList<Address>>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.address)

        addbutton.findViewById<View>(R.id.addbutton).setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, AddAddressActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerview)
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecorator(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.divider)))
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object :
            RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
                Log.e("RecyclerView", "onScrollStateChanged")
            }

            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
            }
        })


        val application = application as CustomApplication
        data = application.database.AddressDao(). getAddressesWithChanges()
        data.observe(this, Observer { words1 ->
            // Update the cached copy of the words in the adapter.
            words1?.let { adapter.updateData(it) }})


    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
class AddressAdapter: RecyclerSwipeAdapter<AddressAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    private var addresses: MutableList<Address> = Collections.emptyList()
    lateinit var  Database:Database

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, itemViewType: Int): ViewHolder =
        ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context).inflate(R.layout.address_item, viewGroup, false))

    override fun getSwipeLayoutResourceId(position: Int): Int {
        return R.id.swipe;
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val fl: Address = addresses[position]
        viewHolder.tv.setText(fl.address)
        viewHolder.swipelayout.setShowMode(SwipeLayout.ShowMode.PullOut)
        // Drag From Right

        // Drag From Right
        viewHolder.swipelayout.addDrag(
            SwipeLayout.DragEdge.Right,
            viewHolder.swipelayout.findViewById(R.id.bottom_wrapper)
        )
        // Handling different events when swiping
        viewHolder.swipelayout.addSwipeListener(object : SwipeLayout.SwipeListener {
            override fun onClose(layout: SwipeLayout) {
                //when the SurfaceView totally cover the BottomView.
            }

            override fun onUpdate(layout: SwipeLayout, leftOffset: Int, topOffset: Int) {
                //you are swiping.
            }

            override fun onStartOpen(layout: SwipeLayout) {}
            override fun onOpen(layout: SwipeLayout) {
            }

            override fun onStartClose(layout: SwipeLayout) {}
            override fun onHandRelease(
                layout: SwipeLayout,
                xvel: Float,
                yvel: Float
            ) {
            }
        })


        viewHolder.tvDelete.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { view ->
            mItemManger.removeShownLayouts(viewHolder.swipelayout)
            addresses.removeAt(position)

           //What should i do here??????????????????????????
           // val address = Address()

           // Database.AddressDao().delete(address)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
            notifyItemRemoved(position)
            notifyItemRemoved(position)
            notifyItemRangeChanged(position, addresses.size)
            mItemManger.closeAllItems()
            Toast.makeText(
                view.context,
                "Deleted " + viewHolder.tv.getText().toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        })


        // mItemManger is member in RecyclerSwipeAdapter Class


        // mItemManger is member in RecyclerSwipeAdapter Class
        mItemManger.bindView(viewHolder.itemView, position)
    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int = addresses.size

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var tv: TextView
        val swipelayout: SwipeLayout
        val tvDelete:TextView



        init {
            tvDelete=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDelete)

            tv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ftv_name)
            swipelayout=itemView.findViewById(R.id.swipe)

        }    }

    fun updateData(addresses:
                   MutableList<Address>) {
        this.addresses = addresses
        notifyDataSetChanged() // TODO: use ListAdapter if animations are needed
    }

}
```

**From the above code I'm able delete a row at a moment but when I revisit the activity it shows that deleted row again**

I want to know how can I delete a data which is stored in room using in `onBindviewHolder`

**As per latest answer suggested by @quealegriamasalegre**

Here is my CustomApplication:--

```
class CustomApplication: Application() {
    lateinit var database: Database
        private set
    lateinit var addressDao: AddressDao
        private set

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        this.database = Room.databaseBuilder<Database>(
            applicationContext,
            Database::class.java, "database"
        ).build()
        addressDao = database.AddressDao()

    }
}
```

Adapter now:

```
      viewHolder.tvDelete.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { view ->
        mItemManger.removeShownLayouts(viewHolder.swipelayout)
        addresses.removeAt(position)

        val application = CustomApplication()

        application.database.AddressDao().deleteAddress(position)//here you delete from DB so its gone for good
        //notifyDataSetChanged() dont do this as it will reexecute onbindviewholder and skip a nice animation provided by android
        //notifyItemRemoved(position) execute only once


        notifyDataSetChanged()
        notifyItemRemoved(position)
        notifyItemRemoved(position)
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, addresses.size)
        mItemManger.closeAllItems()
        Toast.makeText(
            view.context,
            "Deleted " + viewHolder.tv.getText().toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()
    })
```

**Now crashing with     kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property database has not been initialized**

Really need help....

Comment: You don't have to do that: val application = CustomApplication() (it's a core instance initialised by Android). Cast your applicationContext to CustomApplication and get access to the database.

Comment: how should i do this --> `Cast your applicationContext to CustomApplication` @MaximFirsoff in adapter?

Comment: @MaximFirsoff if i do this -->`val application = context as CustomApplication` im getting error as--> `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.`

Comment: Yes that's right, DB access should use in a background thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow my simple steps to solve your issue,

***Step 1:***
Check once `CustomApplication` name mentioned or not in `AndroidManifest.xml`,

```
<application
    android:name=".CustomApplication"
```

otherwise you get this issue

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.AddressActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.example.myapplication.CustomApplication
```

**Step 2:**
Check your module level `build.gradle` file

apply this changes

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

check dependencies -- For Kotlin use **kapt** instead of annotationProcessor

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5"
```

otherwise you get this issue

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for com.example.myapplication.Database. Database_Impl does not exist
```

**Step 3:**
check your `AddressDao` interface, add this function

```
 @Delete
 suspend fun deleteAddress(address: Address)
```

**Step 4:**

in `AddressAdapter` class, add this listener,

```
interface ItemListener {
    fun onItemClicked(address: Address, position: Int)
}
```

add listener variable and setListener function

```
private lateinit var listener: ItemListener

interface ItemListener {
    fun onItemClicked(address: Address, position: Int)
}

fun setListener(listener: ItemListener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

then update your code in tvDelete.setOnClickListener method

```
    viewHolder.tvDelete.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { view ->
        mItemManger.removeShownLayouts(viewHolder.swipelayout)
        addresses.removeAt(position)

        listener.onItemClicked(fl, position)
        
        notifyDataSetChanged()
     //   notifyItemRemoved(position)
     //   notifyItemRangeChanged(position, addresses.size)
        mItemManger.closeAllItems()
        Toast.makeText(
            view.context,
            "Deleted " + viewHolder.tv.getText().toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()
    })
```

**Step 5:**
In `AddressActivity` class, do this changes

Implement listener here,

```
class AddressActivity : AppCompatActivity(), AddressAdapter.ItemListener {
```

then override method

```
override fun onItemClicked(address: Address, position: Int) {
    
}
```

then set listener  for adapter

```
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        adapter.setListener(this)
```

then update code in override method

```
override fun onItemClicked(address: Address, position: Int) {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        val application = application as CustomApplication
        application.database.AddressDao().deleteAddress(address)
    }
}
```

here I used coroutine otherwise you can use AsycTask also

for coroutine add this dependencies in your module `build.gradle` file

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0"
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.0'
```

if you directly called deleteAddress method in UI class, you get this issue

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
```

so use such methods in background thread,

If you really want to execute in main UI thread, do this changes in your code

in `AddressDao` interface,

```
@Delete
fun deleteAddress(address: Address)
```

in `CustomApplication` class, add `allowMainThreadQueries()`

```
class CustomApplication : Application() {
    lateinit var database: Database
        private set
    lateinit var addressDao: AddressDao
        private set

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        this.database = Room.databaseBuilder<Database>(
            applicationContext,
            Database::class.java, "database"
        ).allowMainThreadQueries().build()
        addressDao = database.AddressDao()
    }
}
```

Comment: anyone help me plz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66046272/i-can-auto-increment-id-in-room-database-but-when-refresh-database-its-shows-do

Answer (score 2):

As some of the other responses have said, your main error is that you are not calling delete on your db. Removing an item from your adapter isn't going to be effective if your data set is based on a room db, you have to delete the actual entry.

You don't want to make calls to your db from all over your code, so you'll want to create an interface that will act as a callback to your AddressActivity, which will then make the delete call for you. Define the interface itself in the adapter, as any activity that makes use of that adapter should reference and implement the interface.

In AddressAdapter:

```
interface OnItemSwipeListener {
    fun onItemSwipe(address: Address)
}
```

Then in AdapterActivity, implement the interface and the function

```
class AddressActivity : AppCompatActivity(), AddressAdapter.OnItemSwipeListener {

    ...

    override fun onItemSwipe(address: Address) {
        application.database.AddressDao().delete(address)
    }
```

With this code in place, you need to do two things to connect the implementation in the AddressActivity to the AddressAdapter: 1) Pass the AddressActivity to the AddressAdapter and 2) Call the listener on the swipe events.

In AddressActivity, move the instantiation of the Adapter into the onCreate(...) method

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.address)
        
        val adapter = AddressAdapter(this)
```

Lastly, in AddressAdapter, reconfigure the constructor to take a listener and instead of removing the item from the adapter call the listener

```
class AddressAdapter(val onItemSwipeListener: OnItemSwipeListener): RecyclerSwipeAdapter<AddressAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
        
        ...
        // addresses.removeAt(position)
        onItemSwipeListener.onItemSwipe(address.get(position))
```

That should work for you.

Something that would help you is to give your project a better structure. Google recommends the MVVM architecture with a repository for their projects. It's good that you already have room and livedata in your project, but added structure will help you facilitate changes to your data much more effectively and in a way that's easier to understand. You don't want to be making calls to your db from all over in your code, so this will help keep your db access decreased as well.

**UPDATE:**
I noticed you said you were using swipe to delete the rows, but it looks like from your code that you are actually using a click event. The language for my solution may not be consistent for what you want to name things, but it should work all the same.

Something else to consider would be to extend ListAdapter instead of the swipe adapter you are currently using. Then, instead of needing to implement swipe logic in your adapter, you can set a swipe handler in your Activity where you initialize your adapter and recycler view.

In AddressActivity (I know how to do this in Java, you might have to play with the Kotlin syntax, since this looks funny)

```
val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper( object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,
            ItemTouchHelper.LEFT or ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        override fun onMove(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {
            // do nothing
            return false
        }

        override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
            application.database.AddressDao().delete(adapter.getAddressAt(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition())
        }
    }).attachToRecyclerView(mPostRecyclerView)
```

You will have to create the getAddressAt(pos: Int) function in your adapter, or use whatever method you like for getting the right address object from the adapter.

Comment: plz help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66046272/i-can-auto-increment-id-in-room-database-but-when-refresh-database-its-shows-do

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this:

```
viewHolder.tvDelete.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { view ->
    // this code is to have access to the database inside adapter you should find another way to do it,
    // like pass database in contructor for ex...
    val application = application as CustomApplication
    Database = application.database.AddressDao()
   // main code to delete in db
   GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    Database.delete(addresses[position])
   }
  //

    mItemManger.removeShownLayouts(viewHolder.swipelayout)
    addresses.removeAt(position)
....
```

Answer (score 0):

In Address DAO

```
@Query("DELETE FROM address WHERE id=:id")
fun deleteAddress(id: Int):Int
```

then call it from the position where your swipe operation is done.

Update:

Create an Interface like

```
interface ListItemClick{
    fun onClick(int id)
}
```

implement on your Address activity class and pass this interface to the Adapter.

```
fun updateData(addresses:MutableList<Address>, listener:ListItemClick) {
        this.addresses = addresses
        this.listener = listener
        notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

then, where you implemented swipe to delete, call

```
listener.onClick(item_id)
```

on AddressActivity inside onClick of ListItemClick interface

```
val application = application as CustomApplication
data = application.database.AddressDao().deleteAddress(id)
```

I wrote it here, so some spelling mistake may remain. But,I think you got the basic idea.

Comment: can you tell how should i `call it from the position where your swipe operation is done.` under adapter under `tvdelete`  ...i dont understand how should i call it?

Comment: error at this line -->  `data = application.database.AddressDao().deleteAddress(id) ` indicating that required is livedata<mutablelist<DataCart>> and found is Int

Comment: i have also posted the updated adapter code above ..please see....and updateData1 is never used ...need help ...

Comment: I made an silly error on deleteAddress DAO method, can you check the update one now? And among updateData and updateData1 method, you should delete updateData method. Please let me know if it worked.

Comment: if i make change in `updateData` like adding listener -->it will affect my `add` (here-->        data = application.database.AddressDao(). getAddressesWithChanges()
) in room...thats why i used `updateData1` (separate method)

Comment: Eishon can you please guide me what should i do....need help

Comment: You can use both functions, I just told you that to avoid duplication on your code. Just you have to make sure to call update1 before delete operation.

Comment: where should i call `updateData1` in code? in my edited code?

Comment: After you called adapter.updateData(it) you can call this adapter.updateData1(it, this), but as I previously mentioned, you can you the second one

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are only deleting the row in Kotlin/Java but not in your SQLite room DB. I guess you should be able to solve your problem by simply adding a line that deletes an address in your DB. here an example of how i would do this for your `tvDelete` clickable view:

```
val application = application as CustomApplication
    

viewHolder.tvDelete.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { view ->
        mItemManger.removeShownLayouts(viewHolder.swipelayout)
        addresses.removeAt(position)

        //remember that in onBind you already saved the current Address as "fl"

        application.database.AddressDao().delete(fl)//here you delete from DB so its gone for good
        //notifyDataSetChanged() dont do this as it will reexecute onbindviewholder and skip a nice animation provided by android
        notifyItemRemoved(position)
        //notifyItemRemoved(position) execute only once
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, addresses.size)//i dont think you will need this
        mItemManger.closeAllItems()
        Toast.makeText(
            view.context,
            "Deleted " + viewHolder.tv.getText().toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()
    })
```

so i guess you were quite close already. please mind that i code in java so im not super confident all my code is correct but you get the idea.

Comment: error (red)at `AddressDao()` at code --> `Database.AddressDao().delete(address)` \

Comment: look at my edit. as i said not great at kotlin but if you read the answer you should find the right path

Comment: what i was saying is im unable to access the `AddressDao` after database.

Comment: i just added an edit with what i think is the right sintax for kotlin to instantiate the room db. sorry i was just working with the code you already had there and i didnt think to check it

Comment: crashing with -->    kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property database has not been initialized
 you can see my code edited

Comment: im pretty sure that error comes from a different part of your code. i guess you need to initialize lateinit. also you are trying something that does not work ie using deletePosition (i do not recommend it as it will force you to execute ondatasetchanged() constantly. why are there 2 variables called latinit in your custon application?

Comment: what is lateinit even?

Comment: just please see this post --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63243505/how-to-fetch-edittext-value-from-one-activity-to-recyclerview-of-next-activity

Comment: i have got a answer from above link...like how to add address from ediitext to previous actiivty using room...the above link gave me how to `add` and this post is about how to delete it...please can you help me ...im new to room ...so lateinit is must so as to add the address otherwise functionality will break...

Comment: i think you need to instantiate your db. not sure how this is done in kotlin but here is a link i found https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-room-database/#5

Comment: i created `companion object` as document but still it shows database needs to be initialized-->     kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property database has not been initialized